# How create Batch script to automate DB Dump import into Oracle 11g database with username and password?

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, oracle11g

I need to create a batch script for these following tasks:

1. Drop the oracle User
2. Create the Oracle User the user
3. Grant permission  as dba from sqlplus cammand prompt
4. Importing Oracle 11g dump

And from the command prompt I want to import the Oracle 11g dump.

In normal way these steps I follow always:

step 1: Open the command prompt and start SQL*Plus:

```
  C:\user>sqlplus sys/sys@MySID as sysdba;
```

step 2: Droping existing User

```
 SQL:> DROP USER TEST CASCADE;
```

step 3: Creating User and granting dba permission,

```
 SQL:> CREATE USER TEST identified by test123 default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp quota unlimited on users;
 SQL:> GRANT dba to TEST;
 SQL:> COMMIT;
 SQL:> EXIT;
```

step 4: Back to command prompt importing the oracle dump on newly created user.

```
imp userid ='TEST/test123@MySID' file='D:\Dumps\Oracle\Imported\exp_TEST1_at_MYDEV_20121108.dmp'  log='D:\Dumps\OracleLog\NewImp160913_run.log' rows=y full=y ignore=y;
```

Using these above steps I am able to drop the user, create the user and import the oracle 11g dump successfully.

I need to do these tasks using a batch script.

Comment: so just put all the sql commands in a file and pass that into sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

As a SQLPLUS script (thebatch.sql):

```
DROP USER TEST CASCADE;
CREATE USER TEST identified by test123
    default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp
    quota unlimited on users;
GRANT dba to TEST;
HOST imp userid ='TEST/test123@MySID' file='D:\Dumps\Oracle\Imported\exp_TEST1_at_MYDEV_20121108.dmp'  log='D:\Dumps\OracleLog\NewImp160913_run.log' rows=y full=y ignore=y; 
QUIT
```

Now, I'm not a DOS scripting expert, but you could have a SQL script (the_drop_crt_user.sql) as follows:

```
DROP USER TEST CASCADE;
CREATE USER TEST identified by test123
        default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp
        quota unlimited on users;
GRANT dba to TEST;
QUIT
```

Then a DOS script that runs the sql script and then runs the IMP:

```
SQLPLUS sys/sys@MySID as sysdba @ the_drop_crt_user.sql
IMP userid=.....
```